# Get the number of messages published to a GCP Pub/Sub topic in the last hour

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, metrics

In GCP's Pub/Sub web interface you can see various metrics displayed as a graph, e.g., "Published message count". These graphs have a y-axis in units per seconds. So, the graph tells you the number of messages published per second at any instance of time.

I want to find the *cumulative* number of messages published over a specific duration, e.g., the total number of messages published to a topic in the last 60 minutes. In other words, I want the area under the curve. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GCP Monitoring Metrics Explorer.

- In GCP Console, navigate (from the hamburger menu) to `Monitoring -> Metrics Explorer`
- In the Metrics Explorer page:
  select "Cloud Pub/Sub Topic - Publish Requests" (pubsub.googleapis.com/topic/send/request_count) in the Metric field.

  You can add `topic_id` as filter to get metrics for specific topics.

  Update the `Time Range` (on the top right corner) to the range you would like to get.

  Set the `Alignment function` as **Sum**.

  Leave Grouping as `None`.

  As shown in the screenshot here.
  [image]
- You can also use the Query builder to write MQL.

  ```
    fetch pubsub_topic
    | metric 'pubsub.googleapis.com/topic/send_request_count'
    | filter (resource.topic_id == 'gke-update-notification')
    | group_by 1m,
      [value_send_request_count_aggregate: aggregate(value.send_request_count)]
    | every 1m
  ```
- You can save the chart once you are satisfying with the metrics result. It can then be used in custom dashboard for your Pub/Sub topics.